# Is An aesthetic plot for time series data possible in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I implemented a SARIMA model in R and decided to used a plot in order to visually investigate the performance of my model. Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)
Number_of_visitor <- runif(396, 24000,6600000)
tsdata_trainig <- ts(Number_of_visitor[157:348], frequency = 12, start = c(2003,1))
arima.model <- Arima(tsdata_trainig,order=c(0, 1, 1),
                 seasonal=list(order=c(0, 1, 1), period=12))

forecast_2019 <- predict(arima.model, n.ahead = 12)$pred # Predictions for 2019 to test my model
tsdata_2019_22_observed <- ts(Number_of_visitor[349:396], frequency = 12, start = c(2019,1)) # Observed data from 2019 to 2022
tsdata_post_pandemic_forecast <- ts(predict(arima.model, n.ahead = 48)$pred[13:48],frequency = 12, start = c(2020,1)) # Predictions for 2020, 2021 and 2022 

#Code for plot
ts.plot(forecast_2019, tsdata_2019_22_observed, log = "y", lty = c(1,3), xlab="Year", ylab="Number of Visitors")
lines(tsdata_post_pandemic_forecast,col="red")
```

Here is the plot the above code produces

[image]

As you see, the graph lacks aesthetic. Can someone help me get a better graph please? May be a ggplot?

A plot like this would be great. In my case, `Year` on x axis and `Number of visitors` on y axis should appear and the lines should represent the forecasts and observed values.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use `dput()` to include the `tsdata` object?

Comment: Never heard of dput. Can you please illustrate with data(AirPassengers) instead?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Include a dataset in your question, as well as other variables such as "Number_of_visitor"

Comment: I have made my example reproducible.

Comment: `ggplot2` certainly allows to add aesthetics to the plot, see `?ggplot2::aes`! Out of curiosity, could you provide a graph that does not lack aesthetics, in your opinion? Thanks

Comment: Is `Arima()` a typo (did you mean `arima()`)? If it isn't, please include the package where it came from.

Comment: @jrcalabrese Arima.model works on my PC.

Comment: @DmitryZotikov I have added and aesthetic plot.

Comment: @Günal, then please add any loaded packages to your code (e.g., `library()`).

Comment: @jrcalabrese library(forecast) added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to convert your `ts` objects to dataframes. There are a few ways to do this, but I went with the [`timetk`](https://business-science.github.io/timetk/) package since the code is straightforward. Then you can combine both datasets and plot them using `ggplot()` aesthetics.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(zoo)

Number_of_visitor <- runif(396, 24000, 6600000)
tsdata_trainig <- ts(Number_of_visitor[157:348], frequency = 12, start = c(2003,1))
arima.model <- forecast::Arima(tsdata_trainig, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal=list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))
forecast_2019 <- predict(arima.model, n.ahead = 12)$pred 
tsdata_2019_22_observed <- ts(Number_of_visitor[349:396], frequency = 12, start = c(2019,1)) 

df1 <- timetk::tk_tbl(timetk::tk_tbl(forecast_2019)) %>% mutate(id = "forecast_2019")
df2 <- timetk::tk_tbl(timetk::tk_tbl(tsdata_2019_22_observed)) %>% mutate(id = "tsdata_2019_22_observed")
df3 <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
df3$index <- as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(df3$index)) # convert index to date here

ggplot(df3, aes(x = index, y = value, color = id, linetype = id)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_path() +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("People visited") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed"))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks great @jrcalabrese. Thanks a million. One little issue. On my Mac, The word "Oca", that is Turkish for Jan (January) appears before every year, e.g. "Oca 2019", "Oca 2020". etc  This is because my PC is Turkish. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I updated my code so only the year will appear on the x-axis; neither Jan nor Oca should appear now.

Comment: Thanks. Final issue: When this plot is printed out, there will be no difference between the colors. Is there a way to make one line solid, another dashed etc?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a full reprex where the lines are distinguished by linetype.

Comment: I would like to add another line to the same plot with `nna.model <- nnetar(tsdata_trainig)
ann_forecast <- predict(nna.model, h=48)
df0 <- timetk::tk_tbl(timetk::tk_tbl(ann_forecast)) %>%
  mutate(id = "Ann Model Forecasts")`. However, `df3 <- bind_rows(df0, df1, df2)` does not work because of `df0`. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

We simplify the initial manipulation and then plot using ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)
Number_of_visitor <- runif(396, 24000,6600000)

z <- zooreg(Number_of_visitor, freq = 12, start = 1990)
observed <- window(z, start = "2019-01")
training <- window(z, start = "2003-01", end = "2018-12")

arima.mod <- Arima(training, order = c(0, 1, 1),
                 seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))
forecast_2019 <- predict(arima.mod, n.ahead = 12, se.fit = FALSE) |> as.zoo()
forecast_post <- predict(arima.mod, n.ahead = length(observed), se.fit = FALSE) |>
  tail(-12) |>
  as.zoo()

zz <- cbind(forecast_2019, forecast_post, observed)
autoplot(zz, facet = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "grey")) +
  scale_x_yearmon(format = "%Y") +
  scale_y_log10() + 
  xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. It looks very fancy. How can we replace e+0 with exact numbers?

Comment: Because these are large numbers the e notation seems better but if you want this anyways use   `scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) sprintf("%.0f", x))`   Also look at `prettyNum` or `formatC` to use inside the `labels=` function.